# Angular Data not persist when route changes

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually am new in Angular app am trying to create a simple AddTodo app
Here is my 
`TodosService`

```
this.Todos = this.af.collection('Todos').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        return { id: a.payload.doc.id, ...a.payload.doc.data() }

      })
    })) 
    getTodos() {
    return this.Todos
     }
```

and here is my Todos Component

```
  todos = []
  constructor(private todosService: TodosService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('todos component')
    this.todosService.getTodos().subscribe(todo => {
      this.todos = todo
      console.log(this.todos)
    }) 
  }

  onTodo(todo) {
    this.router.navigate(['/edit', todo.id])
    this.todosService.TodoToEdit(todo)
  }
```

and from `getTodos()` method am getting todos and save it into Todos array

Todos.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="todos.length > 0">
    <ul class="collection">
        <li class="collection-item" (click) = 'onTodo(todo)' style="cursor: pointer;" *ngFor="let todo of todos">
            {{todo.title}}

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in my Todos component.html i have **add** button which basically routes me to `localhost:90/add`
and wheneven i try to go back then todos array get empty how to fix this?

Comment: at first look your angular code looks OK.
When changing the route to /add the list component will be destroyed. If you go back to the list page then the list component will be initialised again and fetch the list again.

Are you sure that `this.af.collection('Todos').snapshotChanges()` always emits an value when you subscribe on it?


You could try to fetch the todos from a simple JSON API (e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ and using the Angular HttpClientModule)

Comment: Please explain this line "this.af.collection('Todos').snapshotChanges()"

Comment: No it's not fetching Again beacuse i have used snapshotChanges() and it's only works when somechanges made in firebase

Comment: @Obaid am getting data when some change is made in databse

Comment: So basically todos array would get populated only when snapshotChanges method would get triggerd, then it has nothing to do with page redirects but rather with changes in firebase...

Comment: If you are new to Angular, you could also try angular-inmemory-web-api
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-inmemory-web-api/

Your first steps with accessing an API with Angular will be easier.

Comment: i get this but how can i get data at once and store it intomy service and access it @Obaid

Answer (score 1):

**This happens because when you navigate to another component, your actual component gets destroyed, losing your todos array.**

What you have to do is placing your TodosService in the providers of todos component parent (for example app component): **this way your todos will not be destroyed**

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [TodosService]
})
```

in *TodosService*

**NOTE: please use @Injectable() instead of @Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})**

```
todos = [];

this.Todos = this.af.collection('Todos').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
  return changes.map(a => {
    return { id: a.payload.doc.id, ...a.payload.doc.data() }
  })
}));

getTodos() {
  this.Todos.subscribe(
    todo => { this.todos = todo; }
  );
}
```

in *TodosCompomponent*

```
get todos() { return this.todosService.todos }
constructor(private todosService: TodosService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('todos component')
  this.todosService.getTodos();
}

onTodo(todo) {
  this.router.navigate(['/edit', todo.id])
  this.todosService.TodoToEdit(todo)
}
```

Comment: This is the same guess I had, but hard to tell since the question didn't post how the service was setup to be injected.  Why are you suggesting to not just use provided in root though?  Unless he needs multiple instances of this component using root should work just fine, right?

Comment: @KyleAnderson You're right, but people keep using root when not needed, having a lot of struggles to understand why the heck things don't work or why there are memory leaks. I'm spreading this idea 'Unless you really need a service everywhere in your app, DON'T use root'

Comment: Ah ok,  I agree with that.  Especially for stateful services you should scope it where it's appropriate.